# Get Status of Service from Remote server and display in div tag VB

Tags: html, css, asp.net, vb.net

Trying to redesign a page and I don't get to code much anymore so I am quite rusty.  I am trying to get the status of a service on a remote network server.  I was using the WMI service in ASP and after extensive reading determined that the ServiceController was a better option.  I want to change the class of a div depending on the status of the service on Page_Load.  This is what I have so far and I am stuck as nothing has worked so far.  I will be displaying a green, red, or orange light image on Running, Stopped, Paused events - all other events will be an off light image.

```
Imports System
Imports System.ServiceProcess
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Web.UI.Page

Public Class _Default
Inherits Page


 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim process As String = "myservicename"
    Dim pserver As String = "myremoteserver"
    Dim sc = New ServiceController(process, pserver)

    If sc.Status = ServiceControllerStatus.Running Then
         <change div tag here>
    End If
 End Sub
End Class
```

The div on the page is setup currently as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server" >    
.....
</head>
<body>
   <form ...
    <div class="info">
       ...
       <div class="element">Service Manager<div id="smstatus" class="icon" runat="server"></div>      
    </div>
```

I have tried to call the smstatus.Attributes.Add with no success. No attempt to call the smstatus id generates anything.  I could use some help on where to start.

wrap-up : I want to be able to check the status of a service on another server and then change the class in the div or panel to an appropriate class. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  the page wasn't being inherited correctly.  This is what I had

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="default" %>
```

This is what I needed

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="Datadash._default" %>
```